# How the get the request data in python that was sent by a nodeJS server using Bottle

Tags: python, node.js, bottle

How to get and print the data that was sent by a nodeJS in python?

I'm using ExpressJS in this nodeJs Module

```
app.use("/py/sendomodel",  function (req, res, next) {
     var oData = {
        "Test":"FirstData"
     }
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        data : oData,
        url: 'https://xxx.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/mprs/omodel',
        headers: {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            /*'Content-Type' :'application/json',*/
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            Host: 'xxxx.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Accept: '*/*',
            'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.15.0'
        }
    };
    return request(options, function (error, response,body,data) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
    });
});
```

Now I'm stuck here, how to print the data that was sent? Here is the python Module

```
from bottle import route, run, post, request, response
@route('/mprs/omodel', method='POST')
def profile():
    #I tried all these without any success , I want to print the oData that I have sent via nodeJs
    #request.body.read().decode('utf8')
    temp = request.body.read()
    #temp = request.json
    #sol = request.forms
    print(temp)   
    #jsonData = json.load(request.body)
    #return jsonData
    return(temp)
```

Comment: What does your code return/print?

Comment: Can you sniff the browser's HTTP request to confirm that your server is getting called the way you expect? (Also please paste the HTTP POST call here; it'll help to debug your problem.)

Comment: @ronrothman Thank you for your advise , after investigating via sniffing my browser, I've came to the conclusion that my header made no sense, removing it kinda fixed my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate things to look at, first is the query second your form data.  I merge the two just in case.  In your example, the body is empty.  Since there is no actual HTML.

```
from bottle import route, run, post, request, response

def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

@post('/mprs/omodel')
def profile():
    payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
    print(payload)
    print(payload['Test'])
    return payload
```